# c3js position of data labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

Is there any possible way to change a positions of labels above the data in `c3` bar chart?
In official documentation there is well explained how to change positions of labels on x and y measurement axis with manipulation of y and x integer, but I did not found anything for data labels.

I've tried to point to it with plain `d3` on which `c3` is based but `console.log` returns me null:

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-texts .c3-text").each(function () {
    var yOrigin = d3.select(this).attr('y');
    console.log(yOrigin);
})
```

because it fires before graph generation. You can see and edit what I'm working on here:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['de', 30],
      ['da', 20],
      ['db', 50],
    ],
    groups: [
      ['de', 'da', 'db']
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    labels: {
      format: {
        y: function(v, id) {
          return id;
        },
      }
    }
  },
  grid: {
    y: {
      lines: [{
        value: 0
      }]
    }
  }
});

d3.selectAll(".c3-texts .c3-text").each(function() {
  var yOrigin = d3.select(this).attr('y');
  console.log('yOrigin:' + yOrigin);
  //d3.select(this).attr('y',100);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to run the code with a delay: http://jsfiddle.net/e60o24d0/2/

Comment: Yea I've managed to get workaround with setTimeout in the end, thank you anyway

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways you can affect those labels:

a. Use `transform` in CSS:

```
.c3-texts .c3-text text {
  transform: translate(-22px, 0);
}
```

b. Select them using D3 in the `onrendered` callback:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    onrendered: () => {
        d3.selectAll('.c3-text').each((v) => {
            console.dir(v);
        });
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, -200, -100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', -50, 150, -150, 150, -50, -150],
            ['data3', -100, 100, -40, 100, -150, -50]
        ],
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        labels: true
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value: 0}]
        }
    }
});
```

This is better than using setTimeout as you then don't have to make an arbitrary guess as to how long it'll take to render the labels before you're able to select them with D3.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  onrendered: () => {
    d3.selectAll('.c3-text').each((v) => {
      console.dir(v);
    });
  },
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, -200, -100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['data2', -50, 150, -150, 150, -50, -150],
      ['data3', -100, 100, -40, 100, -150, -50]
    ],
    groups: [
      ['data1', 'data2']
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    labels: true
  },
  grid: {
    y: {
      lines: [{
        value: 0
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.c3-texts .c3-text text {
  transform: translate(-22px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart">
</div>
```

Comment: Could anybody explain a little more about the answer? What is the meaning to select (using d3) the elements and do nothing? How to move these elements (SVG elements?) by applying transform in javascript but not in CSS?