# C3 - How to center text in donut chart?

Tags: d3.js, svg, c3.js, donut-chart

i have a problem with C3 donut chart - it doesn't center text inside chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/aspirisen/q8h39/83/

```
c3.generate({
  legend: {
    show: false,
    position: 'right'
  },
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 50],
      ['data2', 50],
    ],
    type: 'donut',
    onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
    onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
    onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false
  },
  donut: {
    width: 26,
    label: {
      format: function (value, ratio, id) {
        return (ratio * 100).toFixed(0).toString()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

Ho to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you necessity of that size or is only for the Fiddle?

Comment: @Giordano Yes, the size of the chart must be 100x100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RANT WARNING** -- This is why "helper" libraries built on top of `d3` bother me so much.  Creating this donut chart in straight `d3` is about the same amount of code and you'd have absolute control over things like this.

Regardless, you can fix this by re-computing the centroid after c3 has drawn and re-positioning the text (adjust the radius *r* to move the labels):

```
// find all the labels
d3.selectAll(".c3-chart-arc>text")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i){
    var r = 30, //<-- adjust this to move the labels
        a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 - (Math.PI / 2);
    // compute the new centroid
    return "translate(" + (Math.cos(a) * r) + "," + (Math.sin(a) * r) + ")";
});
```

---

Full code:

```js
c3.generate({
  legend: {
    show: false,
    position: 'right'
  },
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 32],
      ['data2', 50],
    ],
    type: 'donut',
    onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
    onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
    onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false
  },
  donut: {
    width: 26,
    label: {
      format: function (value, ratio, id) {
        return (ratio * 100).toFixed(0).toString()
      }
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(function(){
d3.selectAll(".c3-chart-arc>text")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i){
   var r = 30,
        a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 - (Math.PI / 2);
     console.log("translate(" + (Math.cos(a) * r) + "," + (Math.sin(a) * r) + ")")
    return "translate(" + (Math.cos(a) * r) + "," + (Math.sin(a) * r) + ")";
  });
}, 100);
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try a couple of things.

1. Play about with your chart size and/or font-size. I think this is the easiest solution by far.

[image: examples]

2. Manually position the labels after the chart has been initialized (via `setTimeout` or something similar). (See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149258/c3js-position-of-data-labels) for more info.) To do this, you would need to select all `c3-chart-arc text` elements and then figure out how you want to place them.

   **Downside**: c3 computes the label positions using the centroid of the arc and i'm not sure if there is a better positioning method than that unless you knew beforehand what your output would look like (e.g. only 2 arcs so position the left text to the left and the right text to the right).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i can't change the size of the chart

Comment: can you change the size of the text?

Comment: thanks, I will try. I must say that it is rather strange that such powerful library like C3 has such fundamental flaw